# MagiskSSH ignores $HOME

Tags: android, openssh

I need to integrate an OpenSSH binary into an Android app. (This is a dependency for another binary written for Unix-like OSes and thus cannot easily be substituted with any old SSH library.)

I tried a few things, and the only OpenSSH port I managed to compile for Android was [MagiskSSH](https://gitlab.com/d4rcm4rc/MagiskSSH). With v0.15 (`cdda316f`), at least I got an SSH binary which will run on Android without crashing right away.

However, the MagiskSSH binaries seem to have an odd quirk: wherever standard OpenSSH defaults to `~/.ssh` for a path, MagiskSSH uses `/data/.ssh` instead, regardless of what `$HOME` says. That might work in a rooted environment or in the bootloader, but not inside a user-mode app.

I know that MagiskSSH patches the OpenSSH sources to compile for Android targets. Still I have been unable to spot anything in the patches that looks related to this (though I am by no means an expert on the inner workings of OpenSSH and might easily have overlooked something).

Questions:

- Does MagiskSSH indeed patch OpenSSH in a way that changes the default paths?
- If so, how can I restore standard OpenSSH behavior (other than through OpenSSH command line options)?

Comment: Which version of the MagiskSSH patch did you use?

Comment: v0.15 (`cdda316f`), I’ve updated the question.

Comment: What I meant was: in the [magiskSSH/patches](https://gitlab.com/d4rcm4rc/MagiskSSH/-/tree/master/patches) directory there are ten different patch files for different versions of ssh. Which patch file did you use?

Comment: I didn’t pick one specifically, as the patch is applied automatically during build. Since that build is based on OpenSSH 9.3p1, it should have used the patch for 9.3p1.